# How to display an image with the text before it and after it in the vertical middle of the image?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

On one of my sites, I want to display a simple image gallery with a "PREVIOUS" and "NEXT" text link **vertically center-aligned** before and after each image (respectively) so that my users can easily navigate between images.

How can I do that?  No matter what I try, I simply cannot get it to work.

Comment: do you have an example of the code you're working with?

Comment: Something like: http://www.melin-y-derw.com/our-work/bedrooms ?

Comment: @doublesharp:  I'm using a table with 3 columns and using valign to do the vertical alignment.  First, I think using a table for this is wrong but I don't know any way, and second, even that's not working.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @David:  It doesn't have to be anywhere near as fancy as that.  In other words, the "previous" and "next" links do not need to overlap the image, they need to be before and after it on the same line, just aligned with the vertical center of the image (whose widths and height constantly change).  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The idea was for you to look at the CSS and see how it was done, it may look fancy but how it is done is quite basic, as seen in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with the straightforward solution?

```
<div class="myGallery">
    ​<span>before</span>
    <img src="http://www.spiraluniverse.com/uploads/tx_templavoila/image1.jpg">
    <span>after</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
.myGallery img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

Here are the results:
http://jsfiddle.net/6e87c/embedded/result/

Comment: It seems that sometimes the simplest solution is overlooked. :)  This worked beautifully, seems to be compatible with the most browsers, and requires the least code.  You win!  (Please edit your HTML to fix the missing quote after `"myGallery`.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple technique:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    ​<span>before</span>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
    <span>after</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```css
div span,
div img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGpz6/

This works because you can control the `vertical-align` value for `inline-block` elements. You can't do that for regular `inline` elements, they will always align to the (text) baseline, which is probably what you were experiencing on your website.

Comment: Interesting.  Will this affect all images on the site?  I only want this to affect the specific gallery images (class="gallery").

Comment: So adjust the CSS selectors accordingly, e.g., `.gallery img, .gallery span` instead of `div img, div span`.

Comment: It will affect all images that match the criteria, you'll need to make it more specific. Beware of inline-block as if there's white space (which there is in his example), it can leave a gap between elements (made obvious when they have background colours etc)

Comment: @bfavaretto:  Thanks, so would this be the most direct, "compatible", and "less-hacky" way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Well, I like this solution, but nothing is perfect. You'll note, for example, that `inline-block` elements are affected by whitespace surrounding them in the source code. Not sure if that will be a problem to you or not. As for compatibility, old versions of Firefox (before 3.5, I think) had problems with that, but other than that it's widely supported.

Comment: @bfavaretto:  Hmm...I'm looking for the most compatible solution since I want this to also work on older mobile phones that access the site.  I guess I should have specified that in my OP.

Comment: I don't know much about mobile browser support (they can be a bit tricky), but you can google for compatibility tables of `inline-block` to be sure, and, of course, test on your target devices. As for desktop browsers, I think it's safe to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like on the next / prev links (if they have a class of say .next and .prev):

```
.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
}
.next { right: 0; }
.prev { left: 0; }
.next, .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}
```

The elements .next and .prev are positioned absolutely to their parent (.gallery-container), and they are offset on their location by the top value (which is a % less than 50, if the element is 10% high, it would be top: 45%, if it's 20% in height, it's top: 40% etc).

You'll need to adjust some of the values slightly, such as the left and right properties to match more accurately to the width of the .next / .prev element. If .prev is 40pixels wide, then left: -40px; is what you'll need.

This solution is very customisable and supported in pretty much all browsers.

example HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
  <a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
  <img src="..." />
  <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please explain what this is doing and why you are using such a seemingly-arbitrary number (e.g. 45%)?  Is this solution more widely-compatible (e.g. less "hacky") than bfavaretto's solution above?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But what if the element height changes, how would I know whether to use 45% or some other value?  The gallery has images of different heights/widths and I need the text to be always centered to each individual image.

Comment: It's the height of the .next / .prev element, not the image itself. the % makes it so it will be aligned to the center of the containing block. The containing block will increase / decrease it's own height automatically when the image changes inside it, to make room for it or to remove unneeded room.

Comment: But why does the height of the next / prev elements matter if they will *always* be less than the height of the image?

Comment: Ok lets get to the maths. A perfect center of an elements height is 50% yes? If we set top: 50%; however it will mean the *top* of the link is at the middle, not the middle of the link, causing it to be not exactly in the center. To get it in the center, you take the height of the element you are trying to vertically align, divide by 2, and substract it from 50.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Let me test the solutions presented here for maximum compatibility before awarding the correct answer.

Comment: No problem, if you get stuck, feel free to ask me anything in chat.

Comment: I just tried your HTML & CSS example above and it did not work as intended.  Both "Prev" and the image were aligned all the way to the left (with "Prev" overlapping the image), and "Next" was all the way to the far right.  Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17038/discussion-between-david-and-programmer)

Comment: You've been a huge help, and I really appreciate it!  However, it seems Andrei came up with the simplest, most direct solution, so I've awarded him the answer.  You're an asset to SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `vertical-align` property is [inappliccable to block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

It would be acceptable to use absolute positioning relative to the gallery container in this scenario. After that is done use margins to adjust the position of the buttons, this would force the buttons to remain in place even if the container div gets stretched out vertically (e.g. to accomodate a taller image)

```
.gallery {/*our container element*/
  position:relative;
}
.btn-prev, .btn-next {
  width:40px;height:40px;/*we know the buttons will never change size dynamically*/
  margin:-20px 0;/*so we can use explicit px value to shift them as needed*/
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
.btn-prev {/*remember to correctly position the buttons horizontally*/
  left:0;
}
.btn-next {
  right:0;
}
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/ENuYb/3/)

Comment: Interesting.  This worked, but both buttons were on each extreme of the page, instead of right next to the image on opposite sides.  How can I make links static next to the image such that they don't move when the page is resized?  Thanks.

Comment: @Programmer: um, just adjust the container behaviour? if you need for it to wrap tightly around the image [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/ENuYb/4/) would work